# Advantages of IQueryable<T> over IList<T>

Tags: c#, linq, generics

In C# DAL, What advantages will i derive if i return IQueryable than IList, Iam not using Entity Framework / N Hibernate, just plain old ADO.Net..

Comment: What advantages would returning an IList<T> instead of an IQueryable<T> give you?

Comment: I have not played with IQuerable much, But is IQuerayable in DAL specific to ORM tools..?

Comment: Linq (e.g. Linq to SQL) is an ORM and IQueryable an interface specific to Linq. It's worth noting that IList is part of mscorlib, an assembly specific to Windows whereas the Linq assembly is not.

Comment: I sometimes think of IQueryable like ODBC on steroids-- a major generalization but it helped me conceptualize. Linq is amazing. With Linq you might be querying SQL Server, Oracle, a list of objects in memory, an XML file, makes no difference to the caller. In the old days-- if you had a list of employee data in memory and wanted the top 5 paid for each dept; prior to Linq (IQueryable) you'd probably loop the entire collection comparing salary & department to top-so-far, but now you write a Linq statement and get an IQueryable result.

Answer (score 1):

I believe returning an IQueryable allows lazy enumeration, whilst returning an IList doesn't.

If you return an IList, the query against the database is performed at the point the DAL returns the IList.  Returning an IQueryable, the return can be passed around and the query is only executated when you inspect the contents of the IQueryable.

(This is based on my experience of LINQ to SQL - but I've not checked this against a definitive source)

Comment: In my DAL, i have definitive calls to DB, so there would not be any lazy load,,,i think that we should not use IQueryable  in custom ADO.Net based DAL..

Comment: I would not return IQueryable from the DAL - but would not hesitate in using in within the DAL (to allow several interface functions to use a common base query and then and there on filtering)

Answer (score 1):

You can keep querying against IQueryable.  IQueryable is not for your final return type but good for private helpers which build on original queries - reusable, composable pieces of queries that have an expected return type of the underlying type in your IQueryable<>.

Answer (score -1):

You should return an IEnumerable instead of IList or IQueryable:

**IQueryable** makes the caller think they can use lazy evaluation and add filters, sorting, projection, etc.

**IList** allows the caller to add, remove, reverse, set values, and otherwise modify the returned collection.  This might not be a problem for you, but if you plan on sharing data between calls then you need to watch out for this

**IEnumerable** provides the caller an immutable collection which they know doesn't not support lazy evaluation.

Comment: Indeed most IEnumerables I use are lazy.

Comment: Yes, I didn't mean lazy evaluation.  I meant to say that IQueryable can have the work done remotely (like in the database) whereas IEnumerable cannot.

Comment: Sure it can. You can't know what happens in `IEnumerator.MoveNext()`